# Durian's Errors class rethrow().wrap method invokes compiler error

Tags: java, lambda, checked-exceptions

I am trying to use Errors class of [Durian library](https://github.com/diffplug/durian/blob/v2.0/test/com/diffplug/common/base/ErrorsExample.java), for catching checked exceptions in lambda functions of Java 8.

I wrote simple function:

```
void eat(NsiItemInfoType food) throws CantUpdNSI {}
```

And trying to call it:

this code works well:

```
res.getNsiList().getNsiItemInfo().stream().forEach(Errors.rethrow().wrap(this:: eat) );
```

But this code invokes compiler error **The method wrap(Throwing.Function) is ambiguous for the type Errors.Rethrowing**

```
res.getNsiList().getNsiItemInfo().stream().forEach(Errors.rethrow().wrap(t -> eat(t)) );
```

I can't understand why.

I got examples from here: https://github.com/diffplug/durian/blob/v2.0/test/com/diffplug/common/base/ErrorsExample.java

Durian version: com.diffplug.durian 3.4.0

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue with JRE1.8. Which JRE version are you using exactly ?

Comment: Exactly jdk1.8.0_60

Comment: Tried with jdk1.8.0_60 with no issue. Which IDE do you use (and which version) ?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite  Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201602250958
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Try to update your Eclipse to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

I have to do next, to place brackets over eat()

```
res.getNsiList().getNsiItemInfo().stream().forEach(Errors.rethrow().wrap(t ->{ eat(t); }) );
```